# az vm run-command parameters in key=value format referencing?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

I am running this command:

```
az vm  run-command invoke -g my-group --name my-vm  --command-id RunShellScript  --scripts 'echo "$@"' --parameters 'foo=bar' 'color=red' 'thing=car'
```

Output is:

```
{
"value": [
{
  "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
  "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
  "level": "Info",
  "message": "Enable succeeded: \n[stdout]\nbar red car\n\n[stderr]\n",
  "time": null
  }
 ]
}
```

Where is problem ? 
I dont know how to reference values.

Seems that they are available at run time in env:

```
`az vm  run-command invoke -g my-group --name my-vm  --command-id RunShellScript  --scripts 'env | grep -E "foo|color|thing"' --parameters 'foo=bar' 'color=red' 'thing=car'
```

Output:

```
{
"value": [
{
  "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
  "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
  "level": "Info",
  "message": "Enable succeeded: \n[stdout]\nfoo=bar\nthing=car\ncolor=red\n\n[stderr]\n",
  "time": null
  }
 ]
}
```

If I want to use something like this:

```
az vm  run-command invoke -g my-group --name my-vm  --command-id RunShellScript  --scripts "for i ; do echo ${i} >> vars.file; done" --parameters 'foo=bar' 'color=red' 'thing=car'
```

and then use:

```
source vars.file
```

It will now work, because parameters are parsed as key and value and only values are redirected to vars.file

Of course that I can do something like this:

```
az vm  run-command invoke -g my-group --name my-vm  --command-id RunShellScript  --scripts 'env | grep -E "EXPORTED_"' --parameters 'EXPORTER_foo=bar' 'EXPORTED_color=red' 'EXPORTED_thing=car'
```

,but it is overengeneered and messy solution.

Thanks

Comment: What do you really want? And what is the result you expect?

Comment: vars.file in VM, which I can source in another scripts. In format  foo=bar \n color=red \n thing=car.
Problem is that run-command parse parameters like [foo=]bar [color=]red [thing=]car and if you reference these parameters like bash $@ , then there are only parsed values, not key=value..  Is that clear?

Comment: Yeah, the Azure CLI command is just too simple and not appreciate for you, you can choose another way in the update of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the command [`az vm run-command invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-run-command-invoke), the result that you posted is right and it just shows as a string. So it has no readability. But you will understand the result if run in the Azure Portal.

[image]

And you can refer to the link that I posted to format the parameters which you want to put in the command. And if you just want to show the result of the command, you can add the parameter `--query value[*].message` or `--query value[0].message`.

**Update**

The Azure CLI command can just execute some simple bash command with simple parameters provided. There are serial ways to [run scripts in the Linux VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-scripts-in-vm). You can choose a appreciate one than the Azure CLI.